# Using string values inside "IN" in Informix

Tags: sql, informix

In database table in Informix I have columns like this:

Table name  is `MYTABLE`

**key**            `1234`

**value**    `'POCO','LOCD',MACD'`

Now I want to use this in a query like this

```
select * from table where symbol in (select value from MYTABLE where key='1234');
```

But this query is not working as value is stored as char and

output of `select value from MYTABLE where key='1234'` would be something like

```
"'POCO','LOCD',MACD'"
```

Is there a way to make this work. I want to achieve this in a single query.

Please suggest a better approach.

Comment: It's a poor design - why not let `MYTABLE` contain multiple rows for each `key`, where the values stored are the separate values you're interested in? Then it *would* work exactly as you've written it. (Other future queries will probably benefit also)

Comment: ya i know its not gud design, but this has been designed by others.

Comment: So 'MyTable' is not actually your table, but someone else's table?  One good reason to hate the 'My' prefix to pretty much anything.  It assumes a single user wholly inappropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot interpolate values like that. The database optimiser cannot be expected to know that `value` is going to return a string that looks like a list, which is to be interpreted in a list context.

Since you ask for a better approach…

That design breaks numerous fundamental rules about how databases should be structured. At a minimum, the 'value' column should be a `COLLECTION` data type, so that its role as a list of values is properly articulated. Personally I would create a standard, relational bridging table:

```
MYTABLE
key  col1 col2
1234 ..   .. 

MYVALUE
key  value
1234 POCO
1234 LOCD
1234 MACD
```

This is not the easy way out suggested by others, but it is the *right* answer.

Comment: Hmmm. The other answer that had a self-join and LIKE clause seems to have disappeared now.